# How do I stop calling a function which I set to be called every x seconds?

Tags: javascript, function, timer

I want to make a function stop after 5 seconds of the first call. However I cannot find a proper way to do it. I have created a function which creates a div element with an img in it, putting it randomly in the DOM. I want this function (which creates the div with the img) to be called after 60 seconds for 5 seconds and I want it to be executed in every 10ms between that 5 seconds range. How do I make this work? So far I only achieved the calling with setTimeout after 60s, for I created another function with setInterval which calls the function that creates the img in every 10ms, but I cannot find a way to make it stop after 5 seconds. My guess is I am making this more complicated than it should be, I have tried clearInterval but I am not sure if I did it right.
I basically just want to spam the window with this img for 5 secs then stop the calling.

Please bear in mind that I am new to JS and I do not have much experience yet.

The below pattern is similar to what I have been able to make it work so far, with initial execution but without stopping it.

function createIMG() { creating the div with the img in it and random placement }

function spamIMG() {
setInterval(createIMG, 20)
}

function startIt(){setTimeout(spamIMG, 60000)}

Comment: You can use the functions [clearTimeout](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_cleartimeout.asp) and [clearInterval](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_clearinterval.asp)

Answer (score 0):

As described [here](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_cleartimeout.asp), you can do:

```
var myVar;

function myFunction() {
  myVar = setTimeout(function(){ alert("Hello"); }, 3000);
}

function myStopFunction() {
  clearTimeout(myVar);
}
```